# How to get CPU clock cycles used by process in kernel mode on windows?

Tags: c++, windows, cpu-cycles

As the title suggests I'm interested in obtaining CPU clock cycles used by a process in kernel mode only. I know there is an API called "QueryProcessCycleTime" which returns the CPU clock
cycles used by the threads of the process. But this value includes cycles spent in both user mode and kernel mode. How can I obtain cycles spent in kernel mode only? Do I need to get this using Performance counters? If yes, which one I should use?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

I've just found an interesting article that describes almost what you ask for. It's on [MSDN Internals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163900.aspx).

They write there, that **if** you were using C# or C++/CLI, you could easily get that information from an instance of `System.Diagnostic.Process` class, pointed to the right PID. But it would give you a `TimeSpan` from the `PrivilegedProcessorTime`, so a "pretty time" instead of 'cycles'.

However, they also point out that all that .Net code is actually thin wrapper for unmanaged APIs, so you should be able to easily get it from native C++ too. They were ILDASM'ing that class to show what it calls, but the image is missing. I've just done the same, and it uses the `GetProcessTimes` from `kernel32.dll`

So, again, [MSDN'ing it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683223%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - it returns `LPFILETIME` structures. So, the 'pretty time', not 'cycles', again.

The description of this method points out that if you want to get the clock cycles, you should use [QueryProcessCycleTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684929%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. This actually returns the amount of clock cycles.. but user- and kernel-mode counted together.

Now, summing up:

- you can read userTIME
- you can read kernelTIME
- you can read (user+kernel)CYCLES

So you have almost everything needed. By some simple math:

```
u_cycles = u_time * allcycles / (utime+ktime)
k_cycles = k_time * allcycles / (utime+ktime)
```

Of course this will be some approximation due to rounding etc.

Also, this will has a gotcha: you have to invoke two functions (GetTimes, QueryCycles) to get all the information, so there will be a slight delay between their readings, and therefore all your calculation **will probably slip a little** since the target process still runs and burns the time.

If you cannot allow for this (small?) noise in the measurement, I think you can circumvent it by temporarily **suspending** the process:

- suspend the target
- wait a little and ensure it is suspended
- read first stats
- read second stats
- then resume the process and calculate values

I think this will ensure the two readings to be consistent, but in turn, each such reading will impact the overall performance of the measured process - so  i.e. things like "wall time" will not be measureable any longer, unless you take some corrections for the time spent in suspension..

There may be some better way to get the separate clock cycles, but I have not found them, sorry. You could try looking inside the `QueryProcessCycleTime` and what source it reads the data from - maybe you are lucky and it reads A,B and returns A+B and maybe you could peek what are the sources. I have not checked it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this info, I'll definitely look into it. But as you have mentioned in your last para, I too think there must be an easier way to achieve this. Googling isn't showing much, perhaps it's not common req.

Comment: I've just looked at structure [SYSTEM_THREAD_INFORMATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg750724.aspx) and it passes a `LARGE_INTEGER` which turns out to be `number of 100ns time intervals`.. I start to believe that above-mentioned manual calculation is the best you can have here on winz :/

Comment: btw. there is also some info in a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12606033/computing-cpu-time-in-c-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [GetProcessTimes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683223%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It'll give you the amount of kernel and user time your process has used.

Comment: But does GetProcessTimes return CPU clock cycles? I'm not sure about that.